# Errors "IO error type 6" and "IO error type 13" occur when DolphinDB Python API is used

Tags: python, error-handling, dolphindb

When using DolphinDB Python API  to query data from DolphinDB database, I often encounter two types of errors: `Failed to parse the incoming object with IO error type 6` or `Failed to parse the incoming object with IO error type 13`.

Here's the context:

My server is on WSL1 in a WIN10 subsystem. I use the Python API to query data over a local network. When the execution is successful, the result contains a small amount of data, so the possibility of OOM can be ruled out.

To respond to the issues, I often perform two consecutive queries with a 0.5-second gap and the second query often works.

Does anyone have ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are several troubleshooting approaches you can consider:

1. Network Issues: Check the console for any indications of socket
   errors such as `Socket::write errno=110` or `Socket::read errno=110`.
   Ensure the networks of both the API and the DolphinDB server are
   operational and properly connected to each other.
2. Thread Safety: Ensure that you're not using multiple threads within
   a single session, as it's considered unsafe. Consider using separate
   sessions or employing the DBConnectionPool.
3. Data Validation: Verify whether the type of downloaded data is
   supported for deserialization, or whether the uploaded data is
   invalid.
4. Compatibility: Ensure that the versions of the server and API are
   compatible.